# Where to find Automatic and Manual DocumentDB snapshots in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

I see that AWS DocumentDB is creating automatic snapshots daily and I myself can create manual snapshots from AWS Console. The documentation says that the snapshot is saved in S3 but it is not visible on S3 to me.

I basically want to move the DocumentDB data to S3 in order to propagate it further to other AWS services for monitoring purposes. I was thinking if I can trigger a manual snapshot daily and have a lambda trigger on S3 file upload by DocumentDB.

How can I see the automatic and manual snapshot created by DocumentDB on S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backups in Amazon DocumentDB are stored in service-managed S3 buckets and thus there is no way to access the backups directly.

Two options here are:
1/use mongodump/mongoexport on a schedule: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/backup_restore-dump_restore_import_export_data.html

2/use change streams to incrementally write to S3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/change_streams.html